# how to cut HTML element when page is resized and element is out of bounds?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have img elements on my page that are animated and I don't want those images to be responsive when the page is resized. When I put img it also gives unnecessary space to the bottom. Also left elements work fine but when I put the position to the right after I resize it follows the body container and won't cut.

https://promotions.crocobet.com/p2pGrand/en/?id=null&tk=bnVsbA==

this is the page and left dice and dominos are the img elements. If you change the postion to be right you will see the problem. Also, you can see the space that I dont want in the bottom.
I hope my desctiption is good. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How do you want it to look like when resized to smaller viewports? I am playing around with the screen size and honestly they doesn't look bad at all. No cropping or weird behaviors detected.

Nevertheless, if you don't want these to be displayed in small screens, just media query them with display:none will do the trick

Comment: if you can give .domino-img this     right: -950px; and tri to resize it you will see what problem I have